# controls attribute in HTML is not allowing controls on the video

Tags: html, video, controls

Hi I have tried to use the control attribute in 3 different IDE but it is not working in any of them. I am attaching a file showing my code. Please tell me my mistake.

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>

<title> Started Again </title>

</head>

<body>
     <h1>
This is again I started learning website so that I can benefit others through my knowledge!
     </h1>
     <video width = "700" height = "500" controls>
    <source src = "F:\Steve Jobs Commencement.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your Code Is Fine Just You Need To Add Correct Path I Have Verified You Code By Applying Vedio Link Which Says That Code Is Fine

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>

<title> Started Again </title>

</head>

<body>
     <video width="700" height="500" controls>
  <source src="https://media.istockphoto.com/videos/bluish-mb-concept-with-digital-code-video-id1219346556" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works and solves your given problem just you need to specify correct path by creating one separate folder in F drive **file:/// F: /username / Steve Jobs Commencement.mp4**

Comment: you can click **Run Code Snippet** to check verified output in my answer section